# php curl and HTTP/2 with TLS

Tags: php

How to enable HTTP/2 with TLS?

```
    curl_setopt_array($this->socket, [
        CURLOPT_POST            => true,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => true,
        CURLOPT_VERBOSE         => $verbose,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING        => '',
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION    => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_2_0
    ]);

    curl_setopt($this->socket, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://test');
```

request/response

```
> POST /path/ HTTP/1.1
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```